# MyBatis Spring-Boot Multi-Module configuration BindingException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, ibatis

I'm trying to reach my very simple endpoint (http://localhost:8100/user/1) on my (future) micro-services app with spring-boot and mybatis as mapper but I'm getting this error.

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): fr.mydomain.user.service.UserReadService.findById
```

Saw a lot of people getting this error, I tried every "fix" I saw but nothing is working...

[architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1PkC.png)

UserMapper.java

```
package fr.mydomain.user.mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;

import fr.mydomain.user.model.User;

@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {
    User findById(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

UserMapper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="fr.mydomain.user.mapper.UserMapper">
    <resultMap type="fr.mydomain.user.model.User" id="usermap">
        <id column="id" property="id"/>
    </resultMap>
    <select id="findById" resultMap="usermap">
        SELECT id FROM user
        WHERE id = #{id};
    </select>
</mapper>
```

SqlMapConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<configuration>
   <mappers>
      <mapper resource="fr/mydomain/user/mapper/UserMapper.xml"/>
   </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Is someone can see what am I missing ?

Edit : you can find the project on my github [here](https://github.com/sebberton/MySOQuestions) just need to configure your db

Comment: The error says you are trying to call `fr.mydomain.user.service.UserReadService.findById`, but the actual statement ID is `fr.mydomain.user.mapper.UserMapper.findById`, so there may be some kind of misconfiguration (the service interface is picked up as a mapper?). When it comes to Spring or Spring-Boot, there are various ways to configure the details, so the fastest way to get a useful answer is to share the project (or a repro like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues)) on GitHub or somewhere. If that's not an option, try adding the details for how you load the mappers.

Comment: Thnaks for your comment, I updated my post, you can find my github on it with the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem, it was in my CoreApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "fr.mydomain.user")
@MapperScan("fr.mydomain.user")
public class CoreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CoreApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I thought the MapperScan annotation was looking for Mapper annotation but it's actually considering every class as mapper, so it was considering my service as a mapper ...

```
@MapperScan("fr.mydomain.user") => @MapperScan("fr.mydomain.user.mapper")
```

Comment: I just sent a PR, but this answer is correct. Regarding the scanning behavior, MyBatis-S-B-S looks for `@Mapper` annotation _when_ there is no `@MapperScan`. Note, however, that this scan is performed against the auto-configuration base package which is `fr.mydomain.core` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

can you post you project to github and share project? I alse build maven multi-module sringboot+mybatis and can not running thanks.

Comment: The link to my github is on the bottom of my first post